# XSLT variable set and use in expression

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new in XSLT development and I got a problem, which I don't understand and I have ho idea how to solve this.

I have a xml file with following parts:

```
<Category>
    <MainValue></MainValue>
    <Tree>
        <CategoryLevel1>
            <CategoryLevel1Desc>123</CategoryLevel1Desc>        
        </CategoryLevel1>
        <CategoryLevel2>
            <CategoryLevel2Desc>456</CategoryLevel2Desc>        
        </CategoryLevel2>
    </Tree>
</Category>
```

Now I'd like to fill MainValue using for example this logic

if CategoryLevel1Desc = 123 and CategoryLevel2Desc = 456 -> set  MainValue = ABC
if CategoryLevel1Desc = 123 and CategoryLevel2Desc = 999 -> set  MainValue = DEF
....

I thought I have to create a variable for CategoryLevel1Desc and CategoryLevel2Desc:

```
 <xsl:variable name="VarCategoryLevel1Desc" >
     <xsl:template match="CategoryLevel1Desc"> 
       <xsl:value-of select="CategoryLevel1Desc"/>
     </xsl:template>  </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:variable name="VarCategoryLevel2Desc" >
     ...
 </xsl:variable>


 <xsl:template match="Category">
   <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="$VarCategoryLevel1Desc='123'">     
       <MainValue>ABC</MainValue>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
       <MainValue>DEF</MainValue>
     </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
```

How you can guess I don't have an idea how to solve it. I think my first problem is, how to fill my variables and how can I use them. In some cases the choose expression don't know the variable and 
  Can anyone give me a hint?

Thanks in advance.

Kind regards Stefan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don' think you need to use a variable. You could do something like this. I assume when you said fill you want to keep the rest of the XML document as is?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="MainValue">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="following-sibling::Tree[CategoryLevel1/CategoryLevel1Desc = '123' and CategoryLevel2/CategoryLevel2Desc = '456']">     
            <MainValue>ABC</MainValue>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <MainValue>DEF</MainValue>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```